# Respect of vs Respect from

Tags: prepositions

> My dad has worked hard enough to garner at least some respect **from** his colleagues.

vs.

> My dad has worked hard enough to garner at least some respect **of** his colleagues.

Which preposition follows **respect** here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either preposition can follow *respect*, but there's a problem with your second sentence:

> My dad has worked hard enough to garner at least **some** respect **from** his colleagues. [*okay*]
>
> My dad has worked hard enough to garner at least **the** respect **of** his colleagues. [*corrected*]

For some reason, we definite article when we speak of "respect **of**", while "respect **from**" can be used with more restricted amounts of respect.

> He worked hard and gained a little respect from his colleagues. [*okay*]
>   He worked hard and gained a little respect of his colleagues. [*not okay*]
>   He worked hard and gained the respect of his colleagues. [*okay*]

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20respect%20of%2C%20the%20respect%20from%2C%20some%20respect%20from%2C%20some%20respect%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows that the form "the respect of" is clearly the most often used.

You can view [another ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20respect%20from%2C%20some%20respect%20from%2C%20some%20respect%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) and see that, of the three remaining variants, "some respect from" is the next most commonly found phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[respect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/respect)**

> admiration felt or shown for someone or something that you believe has
>   good ideas or qualities:
>
> *I have great/the greatest respect for his ideas, although I don't
>   agree with them.*
>
> *She is a formidable figure who commands a great deal
>   of respect (= who is greatly admired by others).*
>
> *New teachers have to **earn/gain** the respect **of** their students.*

Notice that I have highlighted the verbs **earn/gain** apart from the preposition **of**. I think that those verbs are usually employed in this context instead of **garner**.

From the same source

> *He inspired respect and devotion **from** his pupils.*

So, I think that you can use both indistinctly.